# Tomcat and Jaas authentication servlet in a form-based security constraint

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jaas, security-constraint

I have a security constraint that covers some pages in my web application. The authentication is made with JAAS and form, and it works fine. (I've successfully implemented my LoginModule).

However I need an alternate authentication via servlet.

That's the code of the servlet:

```
try {
    TokenCallbackHandler tokenCallbackHandler = new TokenCallbackHandler(properties,token);

    LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("myApp", tokenCallbackHandler);
    lc.login();
} catch (LoginException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Debugging the code I saw that the initialize, login and commit were called without error.
The servlet returns an html page with a js that redirect to a protected resource:

```
function doRedirect() {
    location.href = "/protectedPath/ProtectedResource.html";
}
window.setTimeout("doRedirect()", 1);
```

But when the browser tried to get the protected page the app server returns to the login page.

What I am missing?
It is possible that with the js redirect I'm losing the session cookie?
Or, is it possible that the problem is that i'm trying to access (through a redirect) to a protected resource from a unprotected resource?

-- EDIT ---

I've taken a look at the cookies: when I login with the servlet it returns a session cookie and when I try to get a protected resource I can see the browser passing that session cookie to the server, but it seems that it got refused, in fact it respond with another session cookie, going to the login form page

-- EDIT ---

Solved in another way.

After some investigation on tomcat authentication mechanism I realized that what I was trying to do was something wrong.

Having defined a security constraint and a form login config to protect my resources I have tell tomcat to manage authentication in its way. So as long as I didn't pass through tomcat authentication workflow I can't authenticate anything. Also I discovered that it's not possible to configure different login-configuration in the same web application, so having defined form authentication prevents me to authenticate in others way. Probably what I will need is a custom implementations of the class BaseAuthenticator (base class for FormAuthenticator, BasicAuthenticator, etc, containing the code for the respective login configuration) but I'm not sure that it could be a good idea, maybe a security filter will be a better solution.

Knowing anything about security filters in tomcat, I temporarily managed to solve my problem simulating a form authentication in my servlet (really awful, I know).

Comment: Are you creating a session anywhere in you servlet code after successful login ?

Comment: If it gets refused then either the cookie has a path on it that is different, or is it that the cookie is not secure when set, but you're redirecting to a secure endpoint?

Comment: good suggestion, I created a new session in the servlet, but nothing changed, however now I try to play with the intestation, form what i could see form authentication return a set-cookie header.

Comment: I'm redirecting to a page that is in the path covered by the security-costraint. Maybe the cookie is not secure? I have to chek, from now I could see that the cookie start from the browser when i call my servlet and the servlet return that same cookie.

Comment: Is the value of the cookie changing? After logging in, inspect the value of the cookie, and then after the redirect inspect the value. If they are different then that could explain it.

Comment: the cookie is not secure, but from what I can see neither is the cookie returned from the login page. Creating a session it give the id of the cookie sent by the browser, then I thought that returning the same cookie with the right path would be enough, but whatever I'm doing is not working... I think I'm missing something that Tomcat is handling and my servlet not...

Comment: @Brian I controlled that I return exactly the same cookie i'm receiving from the browser, and after the servlet returned its response i tried to access to my security page. I checked that the cookie that the browser sent to my server is the same returned from the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do serious work with authentication and authorization management, you should considere using a well established framework such as [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org) or [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/). The latter at least allows for concurrent authentication schemas (basic http and login form as a default but many others possible)